# Is there an atexit() equivalent for Haxe?

Tags: haxe

Is there a way to register a function which will be run at the end of a Haxe program (or an equivalent technique)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is one in the Haxe Standard Library. For example this wouldn't make sense for JavaScript or the Flash target.

In case of JavaScript you could listen to the window onbeforeclose event.

In case of Flash you could listen to deactivate

On linear platforms; you *could* create your own "lifecycle" by doing this:

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        onStart();
        new MyApplication();
        onExit();
    }

    static function onStart() {
        trace("onStart");
    }

    static function onExit() {
        trace("onExit");
    }
}
```

http://try.haxe.org/#1e5C6 But maybe I'm thinking to simple.

If you are using openFL, this might interest you: http://www.openfl.org/archive/community/programming-haxe/how-to-be-notifed-and-the-application-quits/

Which platform are you targetting?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark. My targets are neko/cpp/flash/js (for now only neko for development and test with cpp from time tot time). The goal was to do some clearnup (e.g. trace some info and close a log file when applicable) when the program is stopped by the user or when an exception occurs. The program is using HaxeFlixel, so I will try the openFL technique you mention.

Comment: Indeed the following works on Neko (handler is called only when quitting the app)


    Lib.current.stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, deactivateHandler);

    private static function deactivateHandler(e:Event):Void {
        trace("DEACTIVATED!");
    }